# Service TO Service Authentication & authorization

Tags: authentication, php, http, web-service, authorization

I have two web services A and B the requests between those services is http.

I want so establish a secure connection between service A and service B to ensure the authorized and authenticate request from the source and insure data was not tampered.

My Application running on PHP "service B -the data store (the server)-".
My client is service from another side "service B -the client or service A-" and programming language we don't care about because we have HTTP Request.

If there are any server side implementation and concept can and body toll me I will appreciate.

I know SSL, but I am looking for something like OAuth protocol but simpler to implement

Comment: I know SSL and HTTPS, but I am looking for something like OAuth protocol but simpler to implement.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [TLS/SSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) protocol which can provide data confidentiality and data integrity. Combined with HTTP, this gives us [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure), which seems to be what you're looking for.